# How to simplify the formula for sums with one variable in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to sum the result of a formula, repeated several times, which has a single value that changes from 1 to 180.The final formula must be contained in a single cell.

[image: my table]

1. Column A contains values ​​from 1 to 180 (to simplify in the example I have only put 13).
2. Cell B1 contains a value expressed as a percentage.
3. Column C (C1 to C13) contains the following formula (cell C1 in the example):
   `=+((1/(1+(A1*1/12*$B$1)))).`
4. Cell C14 contains the sum of all results.

By defining X the variable value of column A, the formula is in practice the following:
[image: formula]

Column A will be not present in my sheet, so therefore I cannot refer my formula to the contents of any cell.
My need is to have only two cells in my sheet: B1, with the rate value; and C1, with the sum of the products with X from 1 to 180. That is what is contained in cell C14.

Thanks for your help and for your patience with my bad English.

Comment: You can use the function `SEQUENCE()` to accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1/(1+(A1:A13*1/12*$B$1)))
```

Comment: there cannot be what? How about you try to change the range to match the sheet?

Comment: Forgive me, there is a missing part in my answer. Column A is not present. Therefore I cannot refer the matrix formula to the contents of any cell.

Comment: Then your question needs to be edited to reflect what you actually have

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SEQUENCE()` function for your problem to replace the column A in your example.

More specifically, you can write the formula:

```
=1/(1+SEQUENCE(180)/12*B1)
```

which will automatically create an array with a length of 180 cells returning your desired series of values.

If you don't want to 'print' out that series at all but only show the sum right away, simply enclose the formula with the `SUM()` function:

```
=SUM(1/(1+SEQUENCE(180)/12*B1))
```